# Execution order in Spark mapPartitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, iterator

When I use Spark mapPatartitions I met something strange, the mutable.HashSet created cannot be properly filled in map process, here is the code:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = List[String]("1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5")
    val result = sc.parallelize(input)
      .mapPartitions((pi: Iterator[String]) => {
        val valuesInPartition = new mutable.HashSet[String]()
        val values = pi.map(line => {
          valuesInPartition.add(line)
          println("processing line: " + line + ", valuesInPartition: " + valuesInPartition)
        })
        println("valuesInPartition: " + valuesInPartition)
        values
      })
    result.collect
  }
}
```

and the output:

```
valuesInPartition: Set()
processing line: 1, valuesInPartition: Set(1)
processing line: 2, valuesInPartition: Set(1, 2)
processing line: 3, valuesInPartition: Set(3, 1, 2)
processing line: 3, valuesInPartition: Set(3, 1, 2)
processing line: 4, valuesInPartition: Set(3, 4, 1, 2)
processing line: 5, valuesInPartition: Set(3, 4, 1, 5, 2)
processing line: 5, valuesInPartition: Set(3, 4, 1, 5, 2)
```

But as I understand, the code inside the mapPartition should be executed in sequential, it is supposed to print the first line at the very end, after the "map" function is finished. But here the Set is printed out without filled value.

I guess I understood something wrong here, please help me to point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spark - the misunderstanding is about the semantics of `Iterator`'s and the `map` method. Remember that an `Iterator` is a way to traverse a structure one element at a time. Calling `pi.map(line => ...)` produces another `Iterator` - but the side-effects involved in producing each element of that `Iterator` are only felt when that element is requested.

Consider the following (plain old Scala) REPL interaction:

```
scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val l2 = l1.map(println)
1
2
3
4
5
l2: List[Unit] = List((), (), (), (), ())

scala> val i1 = Iterator(1,2,3,4,5)
i1: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> val i2 = i1.map(println)         // Look Ma, nothing happened!!
i2: Iterator[Unit] = non-empty iterator

scala> i2.next                          // Request the first element...
1

scala> i2.next                          // Request the second element...
2

scala> val l3 = i2.toList               // Request remaining elements.
3
4
5
l3: List[Unit] = List((), (), ())
```

In your case, the `Iterator` stored in `values` is only traversed *after* you exit the anonymous function (and therefore after `println("valuesInPartition: " + valuesInPartition)`).